# IIS Web Gardening with InProc mode

Tags: .net, asp.net, iis, session-state

I want to ask a question about web gardening in IIS. There is an asp.net 2.0 web application running on IIS 6.0, application run on single worker process and InProc session mode.

I want to run application on multiple worker process(web garden) and i dont want to use either StateServer and SQLServer, Because application retrieve large data from oracle database. If i use stateserver or SQLServer, i think the performance will decrease.

It is possible to run application in InProc mode and multi worker process(about 3-5). But on every request sessionId not change(this is normal) and every request goes to different worker process. Is it possible to say IIS **process same session on same worker process until this worker process is down**.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to implement Sticky Sessions through the load balancer. There is a dicussion on serverfault which may be useful: [Load balanced IIS Servers with ASP.NET InProc Session](https://serverfault.com/questions/19717/load-balanced-iis-servers-with-asp-net-inproc-session).

Comment: Sticky Sessions througth the request to same server, but not always same Worker Process in these Server.  The user says has 3-5 Worker process..